# Start processing files from N-th file in folder

Tags: python, glob

I am using Python to process over 100.000 text files which are in a folder:

```
for f in glob.glob("/folder_path/*.txt"):
 with open(f) as inputfile:
```

Is there a way to start processing from the N-th file in the folder (let's say from the 30.000 th file in the folder), instead of starting over from the 1st file every time in the folder?

I know I can move the files I don't want to process in another file, but since the files are very big it is not a good idea to do that every time, so I would like to have a way to choose which file to start from programmatically...

Comment: Can't you store the file list ahead of the for loop. Then, start the for loop at the Nth file? So instead of "for f in glob..." you store the list "files = glob..." and then start the loop at the Nth element of this list?

Comment: you can also `for f in glob.glob(...)[n:]:`

Comment: @IanAuld write it as a reply and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) can be used in this case:

```
for f in glob.glob(...)[n:]:
    with open(f) as inputfile:
```